# c++ convert a function argument (Struct with template variables) to a string inside a function body

Tags: c++, string, function, templates, struct

I have a template class defined below. I pass the struct to a function like this:

**Function call**

```
function({2, 2})
```

**Function declaration**

```
void function(UnsignedVector2D pad) {
    //get `pad` as a string so that I can write it to file 
}
```

My question is - I want to keep a record on the vales of `pad` that are passed to the function. Is there a way inside the function that I can convert `pad` to a string for example `{2,2}` so that I can write it to a file? I can't extend the function declaration to pass other arguments but could write a `toString()` function perhaps. Is this possible?

```
template <class T>
struct Vector2D
{
    T e0;
    T e1;
};

using "UnsignedVector2D = Vector2D<unsigned_type>;
```

Comment: `2DUnsignedVector` is not a valid identifier. Your example can't possibly compile.

Comment: In C++ you can't declare any names that start with numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty. If you know how to write `toString(UnsignedVector2D)`, then just copy that code over to `function`; or call `toString` from `function`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks - what I meant was how could I write a `toString()` method?

Comment: @arianecathal Just... first do you know how to convert an `int` to a string? Then concatenate multiple strings together?

Comment: You may want to review the section of your favorite C++ textbook that talks about `stringstream` and `ostringstream`

Answer (score 0):

> what I meant was how could I write a toString() method?

You can use an `std::ostringstream` for. You then can create the string as if you were using `std::cout`, below an example for a classic vector:

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "[ "
    for(auto& t : v)
    {
        s << t << ", ";
    }
    s << ']';
    return s.str(); // don't return by reference, would be a temporary!
}
```

Adjust to whatever meets your own needs (accepted data type, formatting, ...).